# What's the most flexible webservice API framework for .NET?

Tags: .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

In considering how to implement a web service for customers to programatically call our service and I've reviewed the Microsoft Web API framework and it looks great, but is this the best, most flexible framework to use?

For example, I'd like to let customers call a RESTful method like this:

/api/products/create

and be as flexible as possible, allowing customers to call it via several different methods

```
HTTP GET:
/api/products/create?name=widget&price=1.99

HTTP POST:
/api/products/create
name=widget&price=1.99


JSON via POST:
/api/products/create
{ "name": "widget", "price": 1.99 }

XML via POST:
/api/products/create
<product><name>widget</name><price>1.99</price></product>
```

and whatever else makes sense. At the end of the day, I don't care how they call it because I just need the inputs to perform the action and I want to allow clients to call it via whatever method they prefer and is easiest for them and then I can respond in the same format or in a specific format if they specify via the Accept request header for example.

Can the Web API framework handle this or is there some other routing framework that works this way so that my controller will be called with a Product model that I can send to my ProductsRepository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API can definitely handle that : )

Here's how you do it. Set up this route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("WebAPI", "api/{controller}/{action}");
```

and create your model and controller like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void Create(string name, decimal price)
    {
        Create(new Product() { Name = name, Price = price });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Create(Product product)
    {
        // Create product
    }
}


[DataContract(Name = "product", Namespace = "")]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Everything you listed above should work with this. The first action will handle the GET, and all three different POST formats you showed should work correctly with the second action as long as the request has the right Content-Type header.

Web API comes by default with formatters that deserialize XML, JSON, and Form URL encoded data, but you can also register your own custom formatters to support even more formats. If you need more information about that, you can find it here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

You've hit on one of the main advantages of using Web API. It makes it really easy to read and expose data in a variety of formats without having to re-write your business logic.